# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.9', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android

When I was coding a game which called diceGame,I tried to build but fault.After I see the warning,I decided to change the gradle version,this is my build.gradle.kts(whole project):

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9" apply false
}
```

I changed "1.9" to "1.80",and it download a lots of jar package and so on.The time I still fail to build the module.So I change to "1.9",but it throw more error,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTZxZ.png)

I forgot some things I have done,I can sure I change the setting.gradle.kts,and build.gradle.kts,I'm the beginningers,I just want to run my android project which called diceGame.

Comment: You are entertin wrong kotlin version ```1.9``` which is not exist. You can select ```1.9.0``` or ```1.9.10```.

Comment: After a period of time,I got these errorL> Task :demodicegame:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: This version (1.4.3) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.8.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please consult the Compose-Kotlin compatibility map located at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin to choose a compatible version pair (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

Comment: Okay with kotlin version 1.9.0 you mist use ComposeCompilernversion 1.5.1 or newer